# HTML Form Input with Radio and Text - Selection

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a text input area attached to a radio button in an HTML form as shown here:

```
    <fieldset class="w100">
                        <div class="rowElem align-left">
                          <input type="radio" id="plan_height" name="plan_height" value="standard6'2&quot;" checked >
                          <label>Standard 6'2"</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="rowElem align-left">
                          <input type="radio" id="other_text" name="plan_height" value="Other height" onclick="document.getElementById('other_height').focus();" >
                          <input type="text" id="other_height" name="plan_height" value="Enter custom height" onFocus="if(this.value=='Enter custom height') this.value='';" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Enter custom height';">
                          <label for="other_text">Other</label>
                        </div>
                       </fieldset>
```

If the user selects the second radio option for "Other," I would like the text box to automatically be in focus for them to enter a value. Also, if the user clicks on the text box to enter a value, I would like the radio button for this to automatically be selected for them.

I've tried using onBlur or onChange or onKeyup on the form element, but can't seem to get it working.

Comment: Are you open to using jQuery?

Comment: Sure, but If possible I'd like to keep it more simple and just include in an onKeyup or onChange form event.

Comment: Can you show how you tried to use onBlur/onChange/onKeyup? Also, can you confirm the ID and value for the first radio control?

Comment: I tried adding `document.form.other_text.checked = true;` on the onBlur event, but it did not work

Comment: I updated the form... All I need now is for the radio button to be selected when the user enters text/clicks on the text input box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/tzj6Z/7/

For cross browser support you'll have to add broswer detection like this

```
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox')>=0) { // Firefox
  focus_event = 'focus';
} else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari')) {  // Opera, Safari/Chrome
  focus_event = 'DOMFocusIn';
} else {  // IE
  focus_event = 'onfocusin';
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything..?

Comment: Do I need to put JS in my JS file? OR just the code in the form?

Comment: If you have an external js file...then include this in that or else include it on the page script tag section. Also it is a good practice to not to include the javascript inline into the markup in order to keep it clean and manageable.

Comment: Hmm... It's working fine in the jsfiddle, but not for me on my site. I put `<script>
var other_radio = document.getElementById('other_text'),
    other_height = document.getElementById('other_height');

other_height.addEventListener('focus',function(){
    other_radio.checked = true;
});
other_radio.addEventListener('change',function(){
    other_height.focus();
});
</script>` in the bottom of my document before the closing body tag, and the onFocus event in place, and it does not check the radio button when I click in the text field.

Comment: If you are viewing it in IE then it won't work because for that you'll have to alter the event names i.e focus will change to onfocus and change will change to onchange

Comment: I'm using Safari (latest release)

Comment: It totally depends on you, either in js file or inside the page script tags.

Comment: I actually figured it out a different way where by I hide/show the fields depending on the selection: [Hide/Show form elements](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9573106/1245596)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the onclick event:  `onclick="document.getElementById('other_height').focus();"`

Comment: That worked to focus on the text field when the radio button is clicked!!! BUT - If the user just clicks in the text box, I need it to automatically select the radio buttong (pretty much the opposite of the code you just gave me)