# HTML Form Toggle Hide/Show fields based on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, forms

On my form (shown below) I have a set of radio options. If the user selects the last option for "Other", I want the div to show and slide down where they can enter a custom value in a text box. I also want to be able to have multiple instances of this same process multiple times in the same form (with different IDs obviously).

Here's how it's set up: If the user selects the radio button who's class is "color_toggle" and the value equals "Other", I want it to show the element id "specify_color_box". If they select a different radio button, I want that same element hidden.

Here's the answer just in case anyone else has the same issue. 
My form element is shown here:

```
<fieldset class="w100">
       <div class="rowElem align-left">
      <input type="radio" id="Gray" name="color" value="Gray" class="color_toggle" checked >
           <label>Gray (Standard)</label>
        </div>
       <div class="rowElem align-left">
            <input type="radio" id="All Yellow" name="color" value="All Yellow" class="color_toggle">
            <label>All Yellow</label>
          </div>
       <div class="rowElem align-left">
        <input type="radio" id="Yellow Posts Black Panels" name="color" value="Yellow Posts Black Panels" class="color_toggle">
          <label>Yellow Posts / Black Panels</label>
         </div>
         <div class="rowElem align-left">
       <input type="radio" id="other_color" name="color" value="Other" class="color_toggle">
        <label>Other</label>
       </div>
       <div id="specify_color_box" class="form-subscr-field rowElem align-left" style="display:none;">
       <label for="specify_color" id="specify_color_label">Specify Custom Color: </label>
       <input id="specify_color" type="text" name="specify_color" class="inputbox" size="10" value="Enter custom color" onFocus="if(this.value=='Enter custom color') this.value='';" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Enter custom color';"/>
      </div>
</fieldset>
```

and my jQuery is shown here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name='color']").click(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Other") {
        $("#specify_color_box").slideDown("fast");
    }
    else{
        $("#specify_color_box").slideUp("fast");
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer just in case anyone else has the same issue. My form element is shown here:

```
<fieldset class="w100">
       <div class="rowElem align-left">
      <input type="radio" id="Gray" name="color" value="Gray" class="color_toggle" checked >
           <label>Gray (Standard)</label>
        </div>
       <div class="rowElem align-left">
            <input type="radio" id="All Yellow" name="color" value="All Yellow" class="color_toggle">
            <label>All Yellow</label>
          </div>
       <div class="rowElem align-left">
        <input type="radio" id="Yellow Posts Black Panels" name="color" value="Yellow Posts Black Panels" class="color_toggle">
          <label>Yellow Posts / Black Panels</label>
         </div>
         <div class="rowElem align-left">
       <input type="radio" id="other_color" name="color" value="Other" class="color_toggle">
        <label>Other</label>
       </div>
       <div id="specify_color_box" class="form-subscr-field rowElem align-left" style="display:none;">
       <label for="specify_color" id="specify_color_label">Specify Custom Color: </label>
       <input id="specify_color" type="text" name="specify_color" class="inputbox" size="10" value="Enter custom color" onFocus="if(this.value=='Enter custom color') this.value='';" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Enter custom color';"/>
      </div>
</fieldset>
```

and my jQuery is shown here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name='color']").click(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Other") {
        $("#specify_color_box").slideDown("fast");
    }
    else{
        $("#specify_color_box").slideUp("fast");
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the checked state of your radio button like this:

```
$('#Other').is(':checked')
```

This way, you don't even have to rely on the value of the radio button - which you could decide to change for whatever reason - just its state.

*Note: if your element has an ID, use it to select it, it's the fastest method. The more complex the selector, the slower the selection !*

---

Applied to your code, it gives the following (inverting the slideUp/slideDown to match the condition correctly):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#specify_color_box").css("display", "none");
    $(".color_toggle").click(function() {
        if ($('#other_color').is(':checked')) {
            $("#specify_color_box").slideDown("fast");
        } else {
            $("#specify_color_box").slideUp("fast");
        }
    });
});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/fQVv6/)**

Comment: I updated my code to what I have now... I tried yours but the box is always open for some reason... can you look at my code at the top and tell me what's up?

Comment: You've changed the ID of the "Other" radio button... Change the code to this: `$('#other_color').is(':checked')`

Comment: For some reason, when I run your code in JSFiddle, it works fine. But when I run it on my site, the text boxes are shown, and the toggle doesn't work?
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/fQVv6/)

Comment: I cannot help with your code if I don't see it, i'm not sitting next to you ;-) Open your javascript console to see if you don't have errors; check your selectors to see if they are ok; place some breakpoints to check the execution of your code...

Comment: :( I don't know what to do....
I don't see any errors, and I don't get why it would work fine in fiddle but not on my site?? Everything else works fine

Comment: Come back to it in a few hours, the problem will appear cristal clear ;-)